# Updating the thumbnail image within the Facebook send button

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I want to update the thumbnail image that Facebook send button uses. I realize that this is cached by Facebook and am trying to update the cache using the [debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

I tried using http://domain.com/path_to_image.jpg?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING on the [debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

However, the old image is still displayed. It appears that the image is being stored at https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?id=path_to_image/image.jpg

Any ways to clear the cache since fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING is not working or am i typing in the wrong url ?

I have also tried adding 
  `<meta property="og:image" content="http://domain.com/new_image.jpg"/>` in my header.php file (I am using Wordpress)

Any idea as to why the image is not updated / cache not cleared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image gets refreshed after a day by the above procedure.

Again, go to the [debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Type in `http://domain.com/path_to_image.jpg?fbrefresh=CAN_BE_ANYTHING`

Answer (score 0):

Great explanation here and clarification that you use debugger on the "FB post" URL (not just the image) and once resolved, use the "rescrape" to force updates on the thumbnail.

http://info.tmrdirect.com/bid/105994/How-To-Change-Facebook-Link-Thumbnail-and-Description

One tip:  in the Debugger tool, I found it only worked if I wrote the URL using HEX for characters (but that might be because that's how my original post was formatted).  e.g.:  https%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2blog2%2F